# Impossible constraints asm

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded-linux

I read a lots of stuff including on this site about impossible constraints asm but can't figure what is wrong with the code `

```
  __asm__ volatile (
"movw r2, #:lower16:_Per_CPU_Information\n"
"movt r2, #:upper16:_Per_CPU_Information\n"
"ldr r3, [r0, %[isrctxoff]]\n"
"ldr sp, [r0, %[spctxoff]]\n"
"ldm r0, {r4-r11, lr}\n"
"str r3, [r2, %[isrpcpuoff]]\n"
"bx lr\n"
:
: [spctxoff] "J" (offsetof(Context_Control, register_sp)),
  [isrctxoff] "J" (offsetof(Context_Control, isr_nest_level)),
  [isrpcpuoff] "J" (offsetof(Per_CPU_Control, isr_nest_level))
);
```

as a tools set I use -gcc-4.8.0 for ARM.
  Has someone a good idea what can be ?

Comment: You didn't post complete code. In particular we are missing the structures you use. The code compiles fine with small test structures I invented. Note that `"J"` expects constants up to 4095 so maybe your structures are really big or something.

Comment: It generally means your syntax is correct however values you are trying to use with instructions are not in valid range.

Comment: You can try widening instructions like `ldr.w`, `str.w` if compiler is insisting of using 16 bit instructions.